# wpf how to fix listbox xaml items order, from left to right, from top to bottom

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i create a system of get images from folder in my project and put it in the listbox like ItemsSource, and i want arrange it like this :

[image]

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

if i resize window like big window, This is what will happen :

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 .. ..
```

but i have a problem arranging the list. and how to get text selectedItem from ItemsSource how?.
here the code :

```
<Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TileTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="Images/folder.png" Margin="10" Height="40" Width="35"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="3,0,0,5" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Names}" Width="70"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="TilePanel">
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="local:LayoutListBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ViewLayout" Value="Tile">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource TilePanel}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TileTemplate}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            
        </Style>
        
    </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: if you want to sort the items, suggest [CollectionViewSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-sort-and-group-data-using-a-view-in-xaml?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: you should show your own efforts.

Comment: you don't want do something because you never did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

Then even when you enlarge the window you will be left with **3 items** in each column